# How to load page with URL containing #tags=green,pink,white at the end

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

So the task is -

Load your page with URL containing #tags=green,pink,white at the end

Write a Javascript that displays the tags from the URL in the list, where each tag is displayed as a separate list item for example, if you have #tags=green,pink,white in the URL, the list will be displayed with 3 items

I'm trying to do this on React,

and I do so,

```
const [ulText, setUlText] = useState(['#green', '#pink', '#white'])

    <ul className='navbar-nav'>
<li className='nav-item'>
    <NavLink className='nav-link' to={ulText[0]}>
        First
    </NavLink>
</li>
<li className='nav-item'>
    <NavLink className='nav-link' to={ulText[1]}>
        Second
    </NavLink>
</li>
<li className='nav-item'>
    <NavLink className='nav-link' to={ulText[2]}>
        Three
    </NavLink>
</li>
    </ul>
```

where the output is

```
const [ulText, setUlText] = useState(['green', 'pink', 'white'])


<ul className='list__ul'>
    {ulText.map((item, index) => (
        <li key={index.toString()} id={item}>
                {item}
        </li>
    ))}
</ul>
```

but maybe I don't quite understand the meaning of the task

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that I can't figure out if I'm doing it correctly according to the conditions, that is, my page should load with the tags green, pink white /#green, then /#pink, then /#white or /#green#pink#white and I don't quite understand how to do it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can get the tags from the URL with `location.hash` which will give you the string "#tags=green,pink,white".

Then you can remove "#tags=" with `substr(6)` (6 being the length of #tags=) and turn the rest into an array with `split(',')`.

```js
const hash = location.hash;
const colors = hash.substr(6).split(',');
console.log(colors);
// colors = ["green", "pink", "white"]
```